# Dajaxice form validation: "unicode object has no attribute get" (jquery serialize)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

i have a big issue with dajax and jquery: i'm trying to save the user's email with dajax, but i keep getting this error when form.is_valid() is called

```
 "unicode" object has no attribute "get"
```

i think this is because of jquery's serialize() method, which i'm using in this function:

```
function send_form(){
    data = $('#subscribe').serialize(true);
    data = decodeURIComponent(data);    
    Dajaxice.tothego_frontend.sito_maynard.subscribe(Dajax.process,{'form':data});
}
```

subscribe is my validation + registration method, which also contains is_valid()

as far as i've understood, the error happens because i'm trying to call the is_valid on a string, but i cannot see other ways to serialize my forms. also, on [dajaxice example page](http://www.dajaxproject.com/fullform/) the validation works fine. my code is pretty much the same, except i'm performing different operations after is_valid() call.

please, i really need some help, been trying everything since yesterday
thanks!

EDIT: [here's the stacktrace](http://pastie.org/2648613)

and here's the form code:

```
class SubscriptionForm(forms.Form):

     email = forms.EmailField()
     what_sub = forms.CharField()
     where_sub = forms.CharField()
     url_sub = forms.CharField()
```

which, as i said at the beginning, is the same as dajaxice's example

Comment: The error is occurring in your form, so post that. And the traceback: it's there for a reason, to help diagnose problems. Post it.

Comment: there you go. bounding the form to request.POST doesn't raise exceptions, but values are empty (and still, i want to understand why i cannot make it work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i fixed it by changing

```
$('#subscribe').serialize(true)
```

into

```
$('#subscribe').serializeObject(true)
```

as i tought, the problem was the structure serialize creates, which isn't good for django form validation

Comment: I've up voted the answer but also want to add a note.  You need a jQuery plug-in for the serializeObject to work.  I thought it was in jQuery but quickly found out it wasn't.  (Although it is linked on the initial post, I think it's important to put as part of the answer).

I used http://danheberden.com/jquery-plugin-serializeobject-2011-04-01/